# Ruta- Abbreviation finding

Tags: uima, ruta

Is there any way to find the abbreviation short before its expansion Using Uima Ruta.

Sample Input Document

Data science” is widely recognized as an increasingly powerful force in the realm of web management and development, as well as in society in general. **ML** is an application of artificial intelligence. On the  He found an **automated teller machine (ATM).** Allowing these companies to realize continuous innovation and improvement in user experience through rapid any time money (ATM) app. These **ATM** latter two companies are working to regain competitive advantages in the evolving web using data science techniques including **natural language processing (NLP)** and **machine learning (ML)**

Problem

I want to get the values, ML alone not **ATM** Because it's used as short form after expansion only. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question as I am not sure if I understand it. Do you want to detect the single ML because you found the abbreviation combined with its long form somewhere else?

Comment: @PeterKluegl ya I need to detect Ml alone because its used before abbreviated.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example how to project annotations using a simplified definition detection. Does that help?

```
PACKAGE uima.example;

DECLARE AbbreviationDefinition;
DECLARE AbbreviationLongform;
DECLARE Abbreviation;

STRINGLIST definedAccronyms;
INT expectedWordcount;

(W[expectedWordcount, expectedWordcount]{-> AbbreviationLongform} 
    SPECIAL.ct=="(" 
    c:@CAP{-> Abbreviation}<-{c{-> expectedWordcount = (c.end-c.begin)};} 
    SPECIAL.ct==")"
    ){-> AbbreviationDefinition};

// TODO check first characters of Abbreviation and AbbreviationLongform and remove annotations again if required

a:Abbreviation{PARTOF(AbbreviationDefinition) -> ADD(definedAccronyms, a.ct)};

MARKFAST(Abbreviation, definedAccronyms);


Abbreviation->{a:@Abbreviation{-> UNMARK(a)} ANY; ANY a:@Abbreviation{-> UNMARK(a)};};
a:Abbreviation{CONTAINS(Abbreviation,2,2) -> UNMARK(a)};
```

DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta

Comment: Let me know if you have questions about these rules.